# Query Time out - sporadic

Tags: asp.net, sql

Have ASP.net web application querying data from a SQL Server 2005 database. Have one page that will sporadically timeout.

Traced the code and found the SQL. Running the SQL through a query tool and it always runs under 2 seconds. The default timeout for sql server is 10 minutes.

The fix for this has been to change the sql server time out to 20 minutes and then back to 10 minutes. Then the page takes the usually 2 seconds to query and display.

Have looked at possible locking but nothing shows that would cause a problem. About the only conclusion is the reseting of timeout setting is killing a process.

Looking for some ideas that can be traced.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 different timeouts at play here. Connection timeout (specified in the connect string and as property of SqlConnection), and query timeout (the property SqlCommand.CommandTimeout). Default values are:

- connection timeout: 15 seconds.
- query timeout: 30 seconds.

Query timeout is defined as "*the cumulative time-out for all network reads during command execution or processing of the results. A time-out can still occur after the first row is returned, and does not include user processing time, only network read time.*"

Lots of reasons why network read time gets consumed (including network contention). Things I would look for:

- blocking in SQL Server.
- statistics out of date.
- execution plan. Do you get a good execution plan in query analyzer?
- Stale/suboptimal execution plan cache. If the problem query is a parameterized stored procedure or query, the execution plan cached is that obtained when the query is first executed. It is based on the parameter values of that first call. If the supplied arguments for that call are outlier/non-normal values, the cached execution plan may well be suboptimal for most executions.
- stored procedure recompiles. A stored procedure that interleaves SQL/DML and DDL (e.g., interleaves SELECT statements with the creation of temp tables) will cause a recompile with every temp table creation. The compile locks prevent other execs of the same stored procedure from proceeding until the execution plan recompilation completes. If you use temp tables, they should be declare up front, prior to the execution of any DML CRUD.

If you specified the connect timeout via the connection string, then existing, pooled SQL Server connections aren't used: you get  fresh connections as the connection pool cache is based on the connect string used. Are you properly Dispose()'ing your connectsion/commands/etc.? If you leave an open reader with data to be read, you're likely leaving a lock in place that cause problems. Sometime, SQL Server chokes, drops the connection and leaves a ghost spid, as well, that poses similar lock contention issues.